# Need some help, to writing a patch file for configure

Tags: makefile, compilation, package, libtool, termux

I am compiling an application "bind-9" for Termux aarch64. My main system is Ubuntu 22.04. For this task, it was downloaded https://github.com/termux/termux-packages and "soft for Ubuntu", "Android SDK" and "Docker-run" are installed from the scripts.

I run the compilation with a script build-package.sh . In the process was written build.sh and patches for compilation. Patches work dynamically because every time the script is run, compilation (configuration) starts with a clean slate and after errors occur, I could not find the cache of my compilation.

As a result, I have an error

```
ld: error: unable to find library -lisc
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
libtool: error: error: relink 'libdns.la' with the above command before installing it
```

before that, the program had already installed

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libisc-9.19.5.so /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libisc-9.19.5.so
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libisc.lai /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libisc.la
```

I understand that it would be necessary to simply add the address to the makefile, but it is not there, it is dynamically generated and deleted immediately after stopping.

The way out is to write another patch, but I don't understand the configuration of the makefile at all((((

what to do, what is the way?

the error falls on the command

```
libtool: install: (cd /root/.termux-build/bind9/src/lib/dns; /bin/bash "/root/.termux-build/bind9/src/libtool"  --silent --tag CC --mode=relink aarch64-linux-android-clang -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat -Wshadow -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=format-security -Werror=parentheses -Werror=implicit -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=vla -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fdiagnostics-show-option -fstack-protector-strong -Oz -pthread -Wl,--export-dynamic -release 9.19.5 -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -fopenmp -static-openmp -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -o libdns.la -rpath /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib libdns_la-acl.lo libdns_la-adb.lo libdns_la-badcache.lo libdns_la-byaddr.lo libdns_la-cache.lo libdns_la-callbacks.lo libdns_la-catz.lo libdns_la-clientinfo.lo libdns_la-compress.lo libdns_la-db.lo libdns_la-dbiterator.lo libdns_la-diff.lo libdns_la-dispatch.lo libdns_la-dlz.lo libdns_la-dns64.lo libdns_la-dnsrps.lo libdns_la-dnssec.lo libdns_la-ds.lo libdns_la-dst_api.lo libdns_la-dst_parse.lo libdns_la-dyndb.lo libdns_la-ecs.lo libdns_la-fixedname.lo libdns_la-forward.lo libdns_la-gssapictx.lo libdns_la-hmac_link.lo libdns_la-ipkeylist.lo libdns_la-iptable.lo libdns_la-journal.lo libdns_la-kasp.lo libdns_la-key.lo libdns_la-keydata.lo libdns_la-keymgr.lo libdns_la-keytable.lo libdns_la-log.lo libdns_la-master.lo libdns_la-masterdump.lo libdns_la-message.lo libdns_la-name.lo libdns_la-ncache.lo libdns_la-nsec.lo libdns_la-nsec3.lo libdns_la-nta.lo libdns_la-openssl_link.lo libdns_la-openssl_shim.lo libdns_la-openssldh_link.lo libdns_la-opensslecdsa_link.lo libdns_la-openssleddsa_link.lo libdns_la-opensslrsa_link.lo libdns_la-order.lo libdns_la-peer.lo libdns_la-private.lo libdns_la-rbt.lo libdns_la-rbtdb.lo libdns_la-rcode.lo libdns_la-rdata.lo libdns_la-rdatalist.lo libdns_la-rdataset.lo libdns_la-rdatasetiter.lo libdns_la-rdataslab.lo libdns_la-request.lo libdns_la-resolver.lo libdns_la-result.lo libdns_la-rootns.lo libdns_la-rpz.lo libdns_la-rrl.lo libdns_la-rriterator.lo libdns_la-sdb.lo libdns_la-sdlz.lo libdns_la-soa.lo libdns_la-ssu.lo libdns_la-ssu_external.lo libdns_la-stats.lo libdns_la-time.lo libdns_la-transport.lo libdns_la-tkey.lo libdns_la-tsec.lo libdns_la-tsig.lo libdns_la-ttl.lo libdns_la-update.lo libdns_la-validator.lo libdns_la-view.lo libdns_la-xfrin.lo libdns_la-zone.lo libdns_la-zoneverify.lo libdns_la-zonekey.lo libdns_la-zt.lo libdns_la-client.lo ../../lib/isc/libisc.la -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -luv -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto )
```

Comment: You will need to add `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib` to your library path, or figure out how to install it somewhere more sensible.

Comment: I'm wondering - where is the loop that forms the contents of the Makefile. I need to write what you say at the end of it.

Comment: as a result, it was necessary to rename in the folder /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib libraries of the type libisc-9.19.5.so in the view libisc.so . Everything was successfully compiled)